# How to pull Video Game info from IGN's api using php

Tags: php, json, curl

I am new to programming and i am making a website that takes video game information from IGN's API (I wanted to use steam's API at first, but i was overwhelmed). I was following along with this link

> https://www.mashape.com/cosmin/ign-com-video-games-rating <

The only thing i can get to work is the CURL request, when i run it in terminal (using a mac) it works fine and pulls the JSON info.

Is there any way to possibly execute the curl code from my .php file? I have been trying to figure this out and looking everywhere and can't find the syntax, or what to do. Below is the PHP code that should be returning the info in a JSON object. How can i echo the info i just requested in my .php file? Any help would be greatly appreciated.​

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://videogamesrating.p.mashape.com/get.php?count=5&game=World+of+Warcraft")
    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "iQCpZr4YWLmsh8ZcjNiXFIJlhYc9p1gsXLFjsnx6zkgaLyLskF")
    .asJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your header info as the second parameter of your `Unirest::get()` call:

```
$url = "https://videogamesrating.p.mashape.com/get.php?count=5&game=World+of+Warcraft";

$headers = array(
    'X-Mashape-Key' => 'iQCpZr4YWLmsh8ZcjNiXFIJlhYc9p1gsXLFjsnx6zkgaLyLskF'
);

HttpResponse response = Unirest.get($url, $headers).asJson();
```